# Outbound Links with Colon in Hash Get Mangled

Tags: url, uri, aem, sling

We have outbound links containing colons which authors have entered into AEM pages using a button component. When the authors enter a link containing a colon, the URL gets [mangled](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html#namespace-mangling) upon rendering. These link to an external system requiring the colon in the hash, which should be fine as specified per the [html spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name)

For example if this URL was entered... 
https://emailgroup.signup.com/#group:this-group

Then Sling and AEM rewrite this URL as shown. https://emailgroup.signup.com/_#group_this-group

Thus breaking the link in the external system. Is there any way to correct/prevent this behavior? Especially when it concerns the URL hash?

Comment: AFAIK, external links are not mangled by AEM. I may be wrong though. Can you check if adding the `https://emailgroup.signup` to the list of Special Link Prefixes in the Day CQ LinkChecker Service solves your issue.

Comment: I added the Special Link Prefix, but it did not have any effect. I also tried disabling CQ Link Checking and Rewriting, which also had no effect on this problem. ... https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableLinkChecker.html#Disablealllinkcheckingbyconfiguration

Comment: Based on the [Sling Mailing List][1] discussion about "Namespace Mangling" I found a solution that works for us. Since the URL's in this particular example do not require a path, removing the slash before the hash seems to work. 

  [1]: http://apache-sling.73963.n3.nabble.com/Outbound-Link-Mangling-td4063708.html